# How to have nested tables overlap parent tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

**First and foremost**: This is for an HTML email, so I want to avoid the use of `div`'s and `margins`.

I have an image which I want to "come out of it's table" and overlap another.

**Here's what my table currently looks like**:

[image]

**Here's what I want it to look like**:

[image]

As you can see, I want the bottom content and 3/4 of the image with a white background, and the top half and 1/4 of the image in the grey background.

Is this possible?

This is what I have so far:

```html
<table bgcolor="#fff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:692px;background-color:#fff;" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="padding-right:0px 20px px 20px;" valign="top">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:100%;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding-top:55px; text-align: center;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:100%;" width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" align="left" style="font-size:20px;line-height:20px;color:#282929;font-family:Arial,sans-serif; text-transform:uppercase; text-align: center;">
                        RECOMMENDED CONTENT
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!-- RED LINE -->
              <td align="center" colspan="2" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:20px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#f01616" height="4" style="height:4px;width:50px;font-size:0px; text-align: center;" width="50"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!----------------->
              <!--NESTED TABLE -->
              <!----------------->
              <td align="left" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
                <table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="background-color:#fff;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
                  <tbody>
                    <!-------------->
                    <!--  IMAGE -->
                    <!--------------->
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#FFF" align="center" style="background-color: #fff;">
                        <img alt="Get the app" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/recommended-image.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ffffff;font-size:20px;vertical-align:bottom; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 50px;">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <!--------------------->
            <!--NESTED TABLE END -->
            <!--------------------->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
                <table bgcolor="#fff" style="background-color: #fff;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#fff" align="center" style="font-size:14px;line-height:18px;color:#282929;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:normal; text-align: center;">
                        Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est am vit elit
                        <br> volores cimpossime serchit, oditiis rehenis volor sequisqui ut late cus,
                        <br> quamus aut optaque pressimendae ipsaereped et adi comnis dolles dellace
                        <br> proreptatur sam, cus aut et ut aceatur, quibuscipsam fuga.
                        <br> Lit qui sequae veliate volorem. Tem ut optatur?
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding-top:25px; padding-bottom: 40px;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;border-radius:5px;background-color:#fff;width:178px;height:40px;">
                        <a href="#" style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;padding:10px 0;border-radius:5px;background-color:#f01616;font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;text-align:center;line-height:20px;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing: 1px;width:178px;" target="_blank">
                     DOWNLOAD NOW
            </a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant for email, then in order to avoid issues around rendering the image in the way you want, I have to say that you need to keep things as simple as possible.

The best way to approach this is to simply include the additional grey into your tablet images, instead of trying to rely on overlapping and transparent images.

Its the difference between spending ages hacking something together, and risking it looking wrong in certain mail clients, and spending a few minutes editing an image.